# Testing a model

Tags: r, logistic, hypothesis-testing

So I hear the term 'testing a model' used a lot. There seems to be a variety of ways to find whether a model has explanatory power (R^2) or if there is an overall significant relationship between the variables (g-test). However, let's say I have data which I acquire each day. Let's say I ran a logistic regression on the past three days of day. Now, I want to know if that model has any explanatory power in explaining data from the newest day. So does this model still hold up if I look at just the newest day of data? I'm just wondering if there's a better way to test a model this way than by simply running that same model on the new dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you don't want to save a part of your data for testing your regression model against although this is very common practice in many epidemiological settings. In those cases I would mostly look for changes in the estimates compared to your original model. Some argue that this is a waste of data and I personally prefer using a bootstrap method where I can have all my data, create a model from it, then bootstrap by using random subsets and see how much overoptimistic my model is (the shrinkage/over-fitting). Currently I use Frank Harrell's [rms-package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rms/index.html) for testing my regression model where the validate function is really useful and easy to use:

```
my_model_fit <- lrm(outcome ~ risk_factor1 + risk_factor2, data=my_dataset, x=T, y=T)
val <- validate(my_model_fit, B=200, Dxy=T)
```

The outcome from validate that I mostly look at is Dxy where `val["Dxy", "index.orig"]` and `val["Dxy", "index.corrected"]`. The shrinkage between the corrected and the original is the value that I'm mostly interested of where if I've udnerstood it right should be less than 0.9. Dxy is also correlated to the predictive C-statistic (Area under the ROC-curve), see the manual:

> The values corresponting to the row Dxy are equal to 2 * (C - 0.5)
>   where C is the C-index or concordance probability.

I hope this gives some insight into the ***testing a model*** strategies. I'm still working my way through Harrell's *Regression modeling strategies* and I can really recommend the book, it is slightly old but I don't think that much has changed.